# What does this schematic of an Op-Amp and Capacitor mean?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, amplifier

I'm still learning about electronics and electricity.

But I'm puzzled by this question from a past exam.

I'm not sure if any voltage is getting across the capacitor, since Vin and 3v are seperated by the capacitor. Maybe if it was an AC Voltage, but I'm not sure even if that can pass through a capacitor.

I tried calculating Vout and ended up with a negative saturated Voltage. 
I have no idea if this is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**My calculations**

[image: op-amp and a capacitor schematic]

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a capacitor. It's a battery.

[image]

Capacitors look like the following

[image]

Notice how the they the plates (horizontal lines) are equal lengths.

The value of this battery is 3V. The node (right side of the battery) is Vin.

Comment: We had an habit to always use a "2 cells" version when doing exercises or exams... so there would be no confusion!